# How to change the parameter name in find function?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

```
public function show($courseid)
{
     $course = course::find($courseid) ;
    return view('admin/showc')->withCourse($course);         

}
```

I have a problem with the `find` function, it searches using `$couseid` as `$id` and I don't have `$id` in the database

I have this error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException (42S22) SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not
>   found: 1054 Unknown column 'courses.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select
>   * from `courses` where `courses`.`id` = cmpe102 limit 1)

Comment: You might be better of using `::where`

Answer (score 3):

The [`find()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#retrieving-single-models) function uses the primary key of the table. By default Eloquent thinks `id` is the primary key of any table. If this is not the case, you have to define the primary key column in the model using `$primaryKey`.

```
class course {
    protected $primaryKey = 'couseid';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to setting `primaryKey` property is using `where()` with `first()` methods because `find()` is just a shortcut for:

```
->where('course_id', $courseId)->first()
```